# ChromeAppにページを内包する

Tags: google-chrome-apps

http://goo.gl/dt5ZWv

こちらのサイトを参考に、chromeのアプリ一覧にアイコンを表示しクリックすると指定したサイトに移動するというものの作り方はわかったのですが、指定したサイトに移動する機能をmanifest.jsonといっしょに置いてある、index.htmlに移動させる方法はないでしょうか？

とりあえず

```
"app": {
      "urls": [
        "index.html"
      ],
  "launch": {
        "web_url": "index.html"
      }
  },
```

このように書き換えてみたのですが全く駄目でした。

方法をご存知の方もしくはアドバイスや不可能だったりする場合ご連絡いただけると嬉しいです。

よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1):

起動した際にhtmlページを表示する、というのは、まさに[オフィシャルサイトのチュートリアル](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app)で行っていますので、これをこのまま書き写せば所望の動作をさせることができると思います。

検索してみたところ、日本語で同等の解説をされている方もいらっしゃいましたので、こちらも参考になるかと思います。
[ChromeApps - Chrome Appsを作る（Packaged Apps編） - Qiita](http://qiita.com/moshisora/items/92e24004c6bf580c71a6)